# Is it allowed to mount GPS/smartphone on windscreen in Switzerland? If so, how?

Tags: switzerland, gps-navigation

I've found out article: https://www.comparis.ch/autoversicherung/news/2014/02/navi-geraet-falsch-montiert-busse.aspx

It states that mounting GPS navigation on windscreen can make you subject to hefty fines, if it blocks your view in anyway.

My car (Fiat Panda) has vents shaped so, it's impossible to mount GPS on them. I've found out no other potential place other than windscreen. Is it possible to mount it there in such a way, I won't be subject to fine? If so, how to do that? Are there any official graphics, for example, showing how to mount it to comply to Swiss law?

Comment: My car has a similar issue in that there is no perfectly flat surface on the dashboard.  But my GPS came with a flat plastic disk with adhesive on the back, which can be stuck to any convenient spot on the dashboard.  Then the GPS itself adheres to the disk by a suction cup.

Answer (score 4):

An alternate answer.  I'm assuming your Panda is not the current model which looks like this:

[image: current Panda]

As this has fairly normal vents, but is more like this:

[image: older Panda]

In this case you still have flat space, there are two possibilities

1. Self adhesive disc

This is a mount size disc which one side sticks to your dashboard, and the sucker on the nav mount sticks to the other (thanks Nate Eldredge). It looks like this:

[image: sat nav disc]

2. Beanbag

This is a weighted beanbag with a space to mount the nav arm, sits free standing on dash, but weight keeps it in place, looks like this:

[image: sat nav bean bag]

So lots of possibilities to think about.

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert on Swiss laws, but have encountered this before.

Main bone of contention is usually where (as you say)  it obscures vision. That doesn't automatically preclude the windscreen,  just where you place it. So mounting the window mount low on the passenger side which you can show is in the extreme of peripheral vison is usually enough.

Also helps with the other issue that comes up,  that of setting it while driving as you can also show you need to either stop to do it, or require the passenger to do it instead.

Comment: Yeah, but if I stop a car to change navi settings, I've got to unbind security belts to reach the navi, much more that is required by even very strict laws forbidding to touch your phone when the engine is off...

Comment: @GeoLog81 forbidden to touch your phone when the engine is off?

Comment: @OmegaTerus yeah, should be 'on'. Still restrictive, in Poland you can do what you want unless the car is in move.