# Is my GPS allowed in Switzerland?

Tags: switzerland, gps-navigation

My GPS is a **TomTom 4PL60 6 Inch Go Premium** or something approximately like this.
I may go to **Switzerland** in the next days.
I read the systems giving radar/cameras information are forbidden in that country, can be confiscated and you may get fined.

By the way I bought this because I wanted the "wide" 6 inch screen and navigation comfort... But it does give some info about radar in various countries. There's a part of the radar info that requires payment and I never paid for it.

I have a vague memory that when I got the GPS I deactivated radar warnings for some countries that forbid it (so Switzerland, and if I remember well Germany and/or Austria), I can't find where this option is anymore.
Earlier this afternoon, I did some upgrades through TomTom's website and it offered me radar stuff, I'm not sure what since I'm not paying for the service, for all EU countries but NOT for Switzerland.

(*At the time of writing there are things that I am unable to check as TomTom
services/website have gone completely wild in my country... like "server busy" "503 Guru Meditation error" *(<-what?)*, or my user profile redirect's me to the Irish or UK site...
Well I'm not sure if it's only in my country, but nothing works at TomTom currently.*)

So is this allowed in Switzerland considering that it didn't offer me radar information for that country ? (although the actual current state of the device vs upgrades is unclear to me)
And if this is forbidden, what other GPS could I use in Switzerland?

Comment: I don't think TomTom *detects* police radar, but maps the fixed locations. What else to use? Since my TomTom deceased I use a free phone app, which does require some data bandwidth (and network access of course) but never needs map updates, and responds to live conditions on the roads. I think there are off-line apps available too, where you pre-load a map. Aside: in UK 'speed cameras' have been redesignated as 'safety cameras' with clear signage, the idea being to prevent you speeding in the first place (especially near known accident black spots). So mapping them isn't illegal.

Comment: I know that there is a different between 'detecting' and receiving position information, but some countries, as Switzerland, forbid both. Now, I realised something, Switzerland actually forbid this since 2007, and I already when there in 2014 with a similar GPS, passed the border at least twice in and twice out, I wasn't aware it was forbidden and nothing happened.

Comment: Perhaps a different aspect, but still relevant. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73880/is-it-allowed-to-mount-gps-smartphone-on-windscreen-in-switzerland-if-so-how

Comment: @EdmundDantes Yeah I read this too. But how old is this other rule? (I was thinking... So You can have stuff in you view, BUT you need to have the swiss highway stick on your front glass ...

Answer (score 6):

(Decided to make this an answer)

The Swiss position on radar warning devices is [here](https://www.ezv.admin.ch/ezv/en/home/information-individuals/bans--restrictions-and-authorisations/radar-warning-devices.html), and it states:

> Radar warning devices (radar wave detection devices, radar detectors,
> driver-alert systems, etc.) alert vehicle drivers via acoustic or
> optical signals to police speed traps. These signals allow drivers who
> are driving too fast to reduce their speed in time before they reach
> the speed trap.
>
> In Switzerland it is **prohibited** to use devices of this nature as well
> as to place them on the market.

But it is so vague<sup>1</sup> that it would seem that the Tom-Tom functionality is forbidden.  However in doing some internet searches, the main topic that keeps coming up is "radar detectors" being illegal.  These are effectively radio receivers that operate on the police radar band.   And that is not what the Tom-Tom does.

However, they also do state on that page:

> The Federal Roads Office ([FEDRO](https://www.astra.admin.ch/astra/en/home.html)) can provide you with information
> on the permissibility of individual device types.

So if you really want to be sure, you should contact the FEDRO and ask for their determination.  However, IMHO, you should be OK with your Tom-Tom - just don't go showing the police the wonderful warnings that the device can generate.

---

<sup>(1) The page I linked to is in English, but I did not look at any of the equivalent French, German or Italian pages.  And I am not sure what the official language(s) for laws in Switzerland have to be published in. So it's possible that the English translation isn't entirely valid.</sup>

Comment: "English is not an official language of the Swiss Confederation. This translation is provided for information purposes only and has no legal force." That's the disclaimer on all the official english translations of laws (at least on fedlex, which has federal laws and regulations).

Answer (score 2):

It should be OK, if you do not activate such service, and often GPS ask you explicit to use it (when travelling in some countries).

The device is not a problem. We use often phone to navigate, and all connected phone can potentially advise you about radars. And we know where the fix radar are placed (and I'm in a canton where the police must advice in advance where radars will be places (but with exceptions), and also radio tend to advise you about them). One strategy that police have is just to move frequently the position. And also they may use radars from a moving car. So now it seems also no more a concern to police (in past it was much more a concern, and so they tried actively to stop it).

So: you can use any GPS devices which have disabled the "radar service".

Just do not speed up too much. There is a low margin before the speed-up can be considered a crime (and not just a traffic penalty), and so handled with normal justice and so much more discretionally, and fees.